# UndefinedMethod api_[model]_url in render:json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have seen this error in many threads, and none of the solutions - which is basically one and it didn't work for me. so perhaps I did something else wrong.

This is my controller: *copied from api on rails tutorial - it worked for the guy..

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    user_password = params[:session][:password]
    user_name = params[:session][:user_name]
    user = user_name.present? && User.find_by(user_name: user_name)

    if user.valid_password? user_password
      sign_in user, store: false
      user.generate_authentication_token!
      user.save
      render json: user, status: 200, location: [:api, user]
    else
      render json: { errors: "Invalid email or password" }, status: 422
    end
  end
end
```

I tried using `location: [:api, :v1, user]` and it still didn't work
I have no idea what I did wrong, and have no idea on where to look for errors. The only difference between me and the tutorial is that I am using Rails 4.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
render json: user, status: 201, location: api_v1_user_path
```

Comment: it's 'api_v1_user_path' as a string - and it works. may I ask how?

Comment: I have no clue why it works.  I was struggling with the same issue, and just tried a few different things till it worked.  Glad you got it sorted.